# Send a recorded file via Filetransfer with Cordova/Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, file-upload, media

I am trying to send a voice recording that I recorded via the Media plugin.

When I try to send the file I get this FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR error:

```
Error opening file /myRecording100.wav: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0xa358640 {NSFilePath=/myRecording100.wav, NSUnderlyingError=0xa34fb30 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
2014-08-06 17:02:26.919 Bring Me[40961:c07] FileTransferError {
    code = 1;
    source = "/myRecording100.wav";
    target = "http://XXXX.xom";
}
```

However, **I can play the voice recording after recording it**.

Why would I be able to play the file (showing that the file was recorded and **saved correctly**) but FileTransfer be **unable to send it?**

Here is my code (for ios):

```
var my_recorder = null;
var mediaFileFullName = null; // iOS
var mediaRecFile = "myRecording100.wav";
var checkFileOnly = false;

/******
 Call when start recording
******/
function startRecording() {
    checkFileOnly = false;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccessFileSystem, function() {
        console.log("***test: failed in creating media file in requestFileSystem");
    });
}

function onSuccessFileSystem(fileSystem) {
    if (checkFileOnly === true) {        
        // Get File and send
        fileSystem.root.getFile(mediaRecFile, { create: false, exclusive: false }, onOK_GetFile, onFail_GetFile);
    }
    else {
        // Create File
        fileSystem.root.getFile(mediaRecFile, { create: true, exclusive: false }, onOK_SaveFile, onFail_GetFile);
      }
}

/* Save the file*/
function onOK_SaveFile(fileEntry) {
    mediaFileFullName = fileEntry.fullPath;
    my_recorder = new Media(mediaFileFullName, 
        function() { document.location ="address_form.html"; // Redirect the user to an other page  },
        function(err) { console.log("playAudio():callback Record Error: "+err);}
    );
    my_recorder.startRecord();
}

/* Get the file and send it */
function onOK_GetFile(fileEntry) {
    mediaFileFullName = fileEntry.fullPath;
    /*
        // Read the recorded file is WORKING !
        my_player = new Media(mediaFileFullName, onMediaCallSuccess, onMediaCallError);
        my_player.play();
    */
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "want";
    options.fileName = "file.wav";
    options.mimeType = "audio/wav";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.params = parameters;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(mediaFileFullName, "https://SERVER_ADDRESS", win, fail, options);
}



/******
    Called when stop recording
******/
function stopRecording() {
    if (my_recorder) {
        my_recorder.stopRecord();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the v1.0 of File plugin, to upload a file in the filesystem via the file-transfer plugin, you'll need to use the .toURL() method to access to it.

> If you are upgrading to a new (1.0.0 or newer) version of File, and
>   you have previously been using entry.fullPath as arguments to
>   download() or upload(), then you will need to change your code to use
>   filesystem URLs instead.
>
> FileEntry.toURL() and DirectoryEntry.toURL() return a filesystem URL
>   of the form

So the correct code is :

```
/* Get the file and send it */
function onOK_GetFile(fileEntry) {

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "want";
    options.fileName = "file.wav";
    options.mimeType = "audio/wav";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.params = parameters;

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileEntry.toURL(), "https://SERVER_ADDRESS", win, fail, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same issue on iOS,and FileUploadOptions didn't work for me.

In case someone is struggling as well, the solution for me has been to switch to LocalFileSystem.Temporary.

Here there is a snippet which shows a full example (**not** tested on Android):

```
var accessType = LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY; // It was LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT;

/** Utility function to return a fileEntry together with the metadata. */
var getFile = function(name, create, successCallback, failCallback) {

    WL.Logger.debug("Request for file " + name + " received, create is " + create + ".");

    var onSuccessFileSystem = function(fileSystem) {

        fileSystem.root.getFile(name, { create: create, exclusive: false },
            function(fileEntry){

                WL.Logger.debug("Success, file entry for " + name + " is " + JSON.stringify(fileEntry));

                fileEntry.getMetadata(function(metadata){
                    WL.Logger.debug("File entry " + name + " metadata is: " + JSON.stringify(metadata));
                    successCallback(fileEntry, metadata);
                }, function(err) {
                    WL.Logger.debug("Fail to retrieve metadata, error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                    if(failCallback) failCallback(err);
                });

            }, 
            function(err) {
                    WL.Logger.error("Failed to retrieve the media file " + name + ".");
                    if(failCallback) failCallback(err);
            });

    }

    window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;

    window.requestFileSystem(accessType, 0, onSuccessFileSystem, function(err) {
        WL.Logger.error("Failed to access file system.");
        if(failCallback) failCallback(err);
    });

};


var Recorder = declare([  ], {

    mediaSrc : null,
    mediaObj : null,

    constructor : function(data, domNode){
        this.mediaSrc = "new_recording.wav";
    },

    startRecord : function() {

        var self = this;

        var startRecording = function(source) {

            var onMediaCallSuccess = function()  { WL.Logger.debug("Media object success."); };
            var onMediaCallError = function(err) { WL.Logger.error("Error on the media object: " + JSON.stringify(err)); };

            self.mediaObj = new Media(source, onMediaCallSuccess, onMediaCallError);
            self.mediaObj.startRecord();

        };

        // On iOS, first I need to create the file and then I can record.
        if (deviceCheck.phone.ios) {
            WL.Logger.debug("iOS detected, making sure the file exists.");
            getFile(this.mediaSrc, true, function(fileEntry){ startRecording(fileEntry.fullPath); });
        } else {
            if (!deviceCheck.phone.android)
                WL.Logger.warn("Don't know the device, trying to record ...");
            else
                WL.Logger.debug("Android detected.");
            startRecording(this.mediaSrc);
        }

    },

    stopRecord : function() {
        this.mediaObj.stopRecord();
        this.mediaObj.release();
    },

    play: function() {

        var p,
            playSuccess = function() { WL.Logger.debug("Play success."); p.release(); },
            playFail = function() { WL.Logger.debug("Play fail."); };

        p = new Media(this.mediaSrc, playSuccess, playFail);
        p.play();

    },

    getData : function(successCallback, failCallback) {

        var fileName = (deviceCheck.phone.android ? "/sdcard/" : "") + this.mediaSrc;

        WL.Logger.debug("Asking for the file entry ... ");

        getFile(this.mediaSrc, false,
                function(fileEntry, metadata) {

                    WL.Logger.debug("Success: I found a file entry: " + fileEntry.nativeURL + ", size is " + metadata.size);

                    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
                        WL.Logger.debug("Success: file retrieved!");
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                            WL.Logger.debug("Sending content and event data to success callback.");
                            successCallback(this.result, metadata, evt);
                        };
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    }, function(err){
                        WL.Logger.error("Error: Impossible to retrieve the file");
                        failCallback(err);
                    })

                }, function(err){
                    WL.Logger.error("Fail: no file entry found: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                    failCallback(err);
                });

    }

});
```

There is a bit of Worklight (debug output) and dojo (declare), but this code could be useful as reference.